# Save attachments by filetype + display random message

Tags: vba, outlook

I have [mAttachmentSaver](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Save-attachments-from-5b6bf54b) VBA code that saves attachments from selected emails.

I would like to save only .pdf, .doc and Excel files. This is to exclude various e-mail attachments such as images within the mail itself.

I was thinking something along the lines of this code I found on the internet `FileFilter:="Excel,.xls;.pdf,".` Not sure where to put that in though.

Also, I would like this line to display a random sentence:

```vb
If lNum > 0 Then
    MsgBox CStr(lNum) & " attachment(s) was(were) saved successfully.", vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
Else
```

For example:

```vb
If lNum > 0 Then
    MsgBox CStr(lNum) & " attachment(s) was(were) saved successfully. Good job! :)", vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
    MsgBox CStr(lNum) & " attachment(s) was(were) saved successfully. Nice work!", vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
    MsgBox CStr(lNum) & " attachment(s) was(were) saved successfully. You got it!", vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
    MsgBox CStr(lNum) & " attachment(s) was(were) saved successfully. Job done! Time for weekend!", vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
Else
```

Comment: For the random look into `rnd`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am a complete and total noob in this sort of thing. However, it would be cool to kinda solve it myself with the help of others. I found this, would it be useful?

Comment: Dim strQuotes(10) As String
    Dim lngIndex As Long
     
    strQuotes(0) = "A"
    strQuotes(1) = "b"
    strQuotes(2) = "c"
    strQuotes(3) = "d"
    strQuotes(4) = "e"
    strQuotes(5) = "f"
    strQuotes(6) = "g"
    strQuotes(7) = "h"
    strQuotes(8) = "i"
    strQuotes(9) = "j"
    strQuotes(10) = "k"
     
    lngIndex = Int((10 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     
    MsgBox strQuotes(lngIndex)
    End Sub

Comment: I think that would work but its hard to read in the comments. Try it out and see if it works. Also take a look at the Answer from Mohit Bansal.

Comment: I've tried a variety of things but every time the code turns red and I get errors. I'm afraid I'm close to having no clue what I'm donig haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at the code and you can add an If condition to filter out the desired formats among the available attachments to be saved.

```
If strAtmtName(1) = "xlsx" Or strAtmtName(1) = "pdf" Or strAtmtName(1) = "doc" Then

Else: GoTo G:

End If
```

[image]

Now you will need to define the Goto tag G as well before the next of current for loop As in the Image.

[image]

So what we are doing is skipping the loop if file extension is not what we require before saving the attachment.

Hope it helps!

Edit:

Amend the Else Condition to reduce the count by 1 as in the image.

[image]

Comment: I think I understand what you did here, You interrupted the 'scanning' to make sure they are the right files. If this is 'true' then we continue to 'g:'. I have fitted it in the code and tested it: it indeed skips the .png test file and only puts 2 files in the destination folder. However, now the message it displays says that 3 attachments were saved succesfull while that includes the .png files.

Comment: Yes You have to amend the message printing as well. Look through the code and try and amend where message is being printed. "lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1"

Comment: I have edited the answer to show where to add this line.

Comment: Hmm I understand what you did but I think -1 would only be correct in this specific test instance. If I would try to save attachments from for example 120 emails of which 5 contain .png files it would then print "119 saved sucessfully" while that would not be correct.

Comment: No That would not be the case. If you look at the code carefully you will find that there are two counters..... one is counting the files in the current mail and other is counting the total files.  In this instance you are reducing 1 from the total number of files in this particular email not the bunch you have selected.      ---------- So if you have selected one email with 5 attachments and one of them is .pdf you will get a msg for 4 files saved.

Comment: Hmm it turns red and I get an error. I think I am too much of a noob to understand what I am doing haha https://imgur.com/a/rC9OFgw

Comment: Is `lCountEachItem` written with a 1 or with an L? @LAWYLAWY . Also What is the error?

Comment: A 1 (one) ---------- hahaha got it!! Thanks :D Works like a charm =D Could you perhaps also push me into the right direction with the other question about the randomized messages? Its more of a gimmick but id like to learn more about this soft of stuff

Comment: Make it an l (lowercase L)

Comment: Thank you very much Mohit and Erazorv :) Is there a way to give a +1 of some sorts?

Answer (score 1):

Mohit's Answer covered the filtering part. Here is the random message part.

Right now it's with 4 messages like the example but if you want to expand it you have to change `Int((4 * Rnd) + 1)`. Change the 4 to something higher like 5 and then you can have 5 random messages. Also add a `Case` statement with a new message then.

```
If lNum > 0 Then
    Dim Message As String
    Message = CStr(lNum) & " attachment(s) was(were) saved successfully."


    Select Case Int((4 * Rnd) + 1)
        Case 1
            Message = Message & " Good job! :)"
        Case 2
            Message = Message & " Nice work!"
        Case 3
            Message = Message & " You got it!"
        Case 4
            Message = Message & " Job done! Time for weekend!"
    End Select
    MsgBox Message, vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I've never really needed VBA but it looks like a pretty fun language to learn, the possibilities seem endless. Especially with Excel. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome :) As you asked how to give a +1 of sorts (in another comment), here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that could help.

Comment: I can't upvote it, don't have the reputation yet :O

Comment: Is alright. Just keep it at having that answer accepted. :)